# How to offset points along a line in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, point, symbology

I used the "Profile from Line" plugin to create evenly spaced points along a line in QGIS, but I'd like to offset them to either side of the line.

I suppose I could draw two lines parallel to the existing one and create evenly spaced points along each of them, and then delete the new lines, but I'm curious if there is a different way to offset points the way I've shown in my MS Paint illustration.

[image: offset points along line]

Comment: Do you want to generate points that have offset co-ordinates, or just display an offset?

Comment: The coordinates don't matter so much, no.

Answer (score 4):

@coelacanth, if you just consider the styling, this is easy using two 'Marker lines', both with interval X, for the first set X/2 as 'offset along line', then set offset Y, for the other set the opposite offset -Y!

[image]